# Set initial default Time value of GUI DateTime Control

Tags: autohotkey

I looked this up and was able to get pretty close to what i'm wanting. My gui is displaying weird time format.

Notice how the time has a `9` after it instead of saying AM and PM ? Why is that and how to correct to just show AM/PM ?
[image]

```
Gui, Add, Text, , Enter working hours
Gui, Add, Text, , StartTime:
FormatTime, Initial_t, 20230101063000, hh:mm tt
Gui, Add, DateTime, x+15 w90 h20 vStartTime 1, % Initial_t

; End Time configuration
Gui, Add, Text, x10 , EndTime:
FormatTime, Final_t, 20230101190000, hh:mm tt
Gui, Add, DateTime, x+18 w90 h20 vEndTime 1, % Final_t
```

Comment: Thomas's response is correct, but just for you to understand why it's showing "A 9" and "P 9."  If you look at the documentation for Gui Control DateTime, you'll see that the variable M (uppercase) refers to the month of the year. Since the date you provided is in the month of September, that's what's displayed in the field, the month 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For your case `Gui, Add, DateTime` should have format as last parameter ([docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/GuiControls.htm#DateTime))
- Initial time can be set with `Choose%TIME%` ([docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/GuiControls.htm#DateTime_Usage))

Example:

```
Gui, Add, Text, , Enter working hours
Gui, Add, Text, , StartTime:
Gui, Add, DateTime, x+15 w200 h20 vStartTime Choose20230101063000, hh:mm tt
Gui, Show
```